# Query date based using milliseconds time on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, unix-timestamp, nosql

I need to search all records that match a date condition. On MongoDB I've a bunch of data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "9ed3b937-0f43-4613-bd58-cb739a8c5bf6",
    "userModels" : {
        "5080" : {
            "generated_date_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413382499442),
            "model_id" : 5080,
        },
    }
    "values" : {}
}
```

I'm not able to convert that NumberLong in something that can be used by this query:

```
db.anonProfile.find({ 
   "userModels.5080.generated_date_timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
});
```

"_id" has been saved as String so I cannot use for a ObjectID search. [btw, is it possible to do?]

Any clue?

Tnx, Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query by

```
db.anonProfile.find({ 
   "userModels.5080.generated_date_timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() }
});
```